# Segmentation fault when running any PHP

Tags: php, segmentation-fault

**Update: I fixed this by running `apt-get upgrade` which updated many php packages, it must of been a buggy php extension which is now fixed**

I have vagrant running homestead (Ubuntu 14.10), when I ssh onto the VM and simply type

`php -v`

or even

`php`

it says

`Segmentation fault`

I'm not even trying to run a script at the moment. I've tried rebooting the VM. How can I go about finding the problem?

Update: I can load php through the browser fine! I seems to just be the cli

Update 2: Strace: http://pastebin.com/txWwLf5k

Comment: Does `php -n -r 'echo "Test\n";'` work?  Maybe a faulty module is being loaded by the CLI

Comment: Nope that fails, I have an `strace` I'll post it

Comment: I managed to fix it by updating all the packages

Answer (score 1):

That's related to memory allocation.
The cause could be a faulty PHP configuration, for example see if the 'memory_limit' value in php.ini is below the one the machine offers.
If in doubt, read about "shared memory" setting for your OS.